# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I am using firebase firestore for my app. Whenever I try to call `firebase.firestore().collection("users")`, I get `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')`. I have no idea what this error means as in my previous project, I used firestore and nothing of this sort came up. I have also recently upgraded my expo client, but I am not sure that the new version is the issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue. Downgraded the firebase version to @7.12.0 and it worked again.

Comment: Let me know if you are able to get your data to show. I can only get my information to show in debug mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. From what I have experienced, it seems that I needed to uninstall firebase from my project with `npm uninstall firebase`. Then, I had to reinstall firebase and @firebase/firestore using expo like so `expo install firebase @firebase/firestore`. From there, I did `import * as firebase from "firebase"` and `import "@firebase/firestore` in my file.

Comment: Came here for exact same problem, but this didn't work for me. I even tried removing Firebase and @Firebase from module folder and then reinstall using your approach. I there anything else i can try?

Comment: Not really sure what else I could recommend. I guess you could look in your package.json file and see if you have any firebase related packages and reinstall all of those.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened when I upgraded to Expo SDK 37.
And I solved it by updating android studio and Android SDK.
https://www.javadrive.jp/android/install/index3.html#section2